# Gulp debugging - piping to process.stdout gives TypeError('invalid data')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I am trying to debug Gulp task I wrote. I tried using `'gulp-debug'` module but all it really does is just stat a file...which isn't usefull for me.

For starters, how can I make the process go to the terminal? I wan to see what `wiredep` is outputing. I tried `.pipe(process.stdout)` but I got `TypeError('invalid data')`.

```
var bowerStream = gulp.src('./app/bower_components')
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(process.stdout)
```

Comment: https://github.com/geejs/gulp-tap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [through2](https://github.com/rvagg/through2) this is possible:

```
gulp.src('./app/index.html')
  .pipe(wiredep({directory: './app/bower_components'}))
  .pipe(through2.obj(function(obj, enc, next) {
    this.push(obj.contents);
    next();
  })).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: It seems like you found your own answer, but since the SO style of Q&A is about providing long-term quality answers, the preferred style is for you to provide your own answer is a full explanatory manner.  For instance, what is the role of this '`through2`' and related function?

Comment: I did, as I gave the link to `through2` in which it is up to you to go and learn about it. If you click on that link and learn about it, you will know the role and related function.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is somewhat late however, I just wrote a blog post about how to debug gulp tasks in visual studio code: 
https://hansrwindhoff.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/debugging-task-runner-tasks-like-gulp-with-visual-studio-code-editordebugger/

You can start the VSCode debugger to run the gulp task and then do full source level debugging on all your plugins and gulpfiles. Very handy!